# How to make space between points MPAndroidChart LineChart?

Tags: android, charts, mpandroidchart

I use [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart), but cant make space between points. [now I have this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BfQlY.png) after opening my chart, but want to have [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NAE3p.png) .

Comment: set the x axis labels

Comment: I try to use XAxis xAxis= lineChart.getXAxis(); xAxis.setSpaceBetweenLabels(50); But it does not help. The labels has space between each other like : "20-10 space space spase 06-11". But points inside the chart the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want tho reduce the maximum amount of values that can be shown at once, use this:
`chart.setVisibleXRangeMaximum(10)`

Its all in the wiki: https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki/Modifying-the-Viewport

Comment: @Philipp Jahoda, Hi Phil, I need to show all the available x-axis labels at once without zoom. I have used the previous version of method call in order to set it with setSpaceBetweenLabels(0). It's now deprecated with version 3.0.0. What is the alternate with current version.